# SQL WHERE AND & OR Clauses

Tags: sql

I am attempting to execute this SQL statement, and while it does indeed execute, it does not return the expected result. Below is the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE SubnetID.ID = '2' 
  AND Subnets.DomainName LIKE '%tns%' 
  OR Subnets.ServerID LIKE '%tns%' 
  OR CONCAT(SubnetID.IP_Prefix,'.',Subnets.LastOctet) LIKE '%tns%' 
  OR Servers.Name LIKE '%tns%' 
  OR Subnets.Comment LIKE '%tns%'
```

What happens is the WHERE SubnetID.ID = '2' line seems to be completely disregarded as I return rows with the SubnetID.ID set to values other than '2'. It is processing LIKE clauses, it is just not filtering out the SubnetID.ID values.

I am thinking this has to do with using AND/OR/LIKE together, but I am not sure.

Comment: Minor note, I added a single quote to the end of your where clause making the assumption this is a copy / paste error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
WHERE SubnetID.ID = '2' AND 
(
  Subnets.DomainName LIKE '%tns%' OR
  Subnets.ServerID LIKE '%tns%' OR
  CONCAT(SubnetID.IP_Prefix,'.',Subnets.LastOctet) LIKE '%tns%' OR
  Servers.Name LIKE '%tns%' OR
  Subnets.Comment LIKE '%tns%'
)
```

Your query was executed this way

```
WHERE (
  SubnetID.ID = '2' AND 
  Subnets.DomainName LIKE '%tns%'
) OR
(Subnets.ServerID LIKE '%tns%') OR
(CONCAT(SubnetID.IP_Prefix,'.',Subnets.LastOctet) LIKE '%tns%') OR
(Servers.Name LIKE '%tns%') OR
(Subnets.Comment LIKE '%tns%')
```

Comment: As per pretty much every other language... no?

Comment: Indeed... So I just needed to encapsulate my ...LIKE...OR...statements in parentheses to seperate it from the main SubnetID.ID = statement

Comment: Yes `and` is stronger as `or`. In your query all elements where selected that had the id and domeinname like, or all elements that matches any of the other likes.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
WHERE SubnetID.ID = '2' AND 
( Subnets.DomainName LIKE '%tns%' 
  OR Subnets.ServerID LIKE '%tns%' 
  OR CONCAT(SubnetID.IP_Prefix,'.',Subnets.LastOctet) LIKE '%tns%' 
  OR Servers.Name LIKE '%tns%' 
  OR Subnets.Comment LIKE '%tns%
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The operator precedence is most likely what is causing the problem. Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) from microsoft if you are using one of their DBMS products.